# Is it preposterous to have 2 different light sources in a design project?

Tags: vector

I am working on a branding skyline for a company, and I'm using a top-left light source for the geometric buildings, but then my ground landscape and trees are using a top-right light source.

My question is it this is acceptable in terms of design. I mean, my initial thoughts were to create a left-to-right sense of movement, but the opposing light source may be helped to create balance in the design. Does this idea make sense, or am I totally wrong? I know consistency plays a big role, but it's not looking that crazy.

Here's the image **(not all buildings are right yet, only the far left one if correct).**

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Is it preposterous to have more than one lighting source in real life? No. There are reflections and man-made lights after all. Do what makes the most sense to you and your project needs. It would probably be a good idea to have one primary lighting source in comparison to any other lighting sources being used as that would look more natural to our eyes. Unless you live on Tatooine.

Comment: I completely agree (also with the Tatooine statement), one main source of light, and as many other softer ones as required.

Comment: Yes, I completely agree with @bemdesign - it's actually very rare for anything to have a single light source. Just be wary of causing confusion with shadows falling where they don't belong or secondary source(s) overpowering your primary source(s). Having said that, many designs violate these "rules" purposefully and to good effect.